# Python MYSQL 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-25: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to parse a Russian web-site (in Cyrillic) and insert data to a mySQL DB. The parsing is fine, but I can't save the data in the DB because of the Cyrillic letters. Python give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/vape_map.py", line 40, in <module>
    print parse_shop_meta()
  File "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/vape_map.py", line 35, in parse_shop_meta
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",(shop_title, shop_address, shop_phone, shop_site, shop_desc))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My code:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
import csv
import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="***", db="vape_map", charset='utf8')

def get_shop_urls():
    i = 1
    all_shop_urls = []
    while i < 2:
        url = requests.get("http://vapemap.ru/shop/?city=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&page={}".format(i))
        page_html = fromstring(url.content)
        shop_urls = page_html.xpath('//h3[@class="title"]/a/@href')
        all_shop_urls += shop_urls
        i +=1
    return all_shop_urls

def parse_shop_meta():
    shops_meta = []
    csvfile = open('vape_shops.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    for shop in get_shop_urls():
        url = requests.get("http://vapemap.ru{}".format(shop), 'utf-8')
        page_html = fromstring(url.content)
        shop_title = page_html.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()')
        shop_address = page_html.xpath('//div[@class="address"]/text()')
        shop_phone = page_html.xpath('//div[@class="phone"]/a/text()')
        shop_site = page_html.xpath('//div[@class="site"]/a/text()')
        shop_desc = page_html.xpath('//div[@class="shop-desc"]/text()')
        sql = """INSERT INTO vape_shops(title, address, phone, site, description)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",(shop_title, shop_address, shop_phone, shop_site, shop_desc)
        cursor.execute(sql, (shop_title[0], shop_address[0], shop_phone[0], shop_site[0], shop_desc[0]))
        db.commit()
    db.close()
    return shops_meta

print parse_shop_meta()
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, I suggest you print `url.encoding` after your `GET` request to see if the guess made by the `requests` module is in fact a good one. Otherwise, you may want to change the encoding with `url.encoding = 'YOUR ENCODING HERE'`. Also, you can try and `decode` the strings you're using in `sql` query. Finally, are you sure you're formatting that `sql` query properly? It looks like you're creating a tuple.

Comment: Try `unicode(your_string, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')` for all of the things that you're inserting into your db.

Comment: Abdou, i saw error about tuple. My MYSQL skills not so good. Can you help to my with this code? I need to insert shop (on cyrillic ) in my DB

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov please provide a full stacktrace

Comment: Alastair McCormack, added

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov take a look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcfcc6v0e8f98dg/vapeshops.py?dl=0). It could be a good starting point. I retouched your original script a little bit. I also use `pymysql` instead of `mysqldb`. But it should not matter much, as long as you're able to connect to your database without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0` is the encoding for `Москва`, so that looks OK.  But you also need to establish that utf8 will be used in the connection to MySQL.  And specify that the target column is `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and [Python-specifics](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)